# How to check broken links in a webpage using Casperjs?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, casperjs, broken-links

I want to check all broken links present in a webpage using casperjs. I write following code but it not working:

```
casper.then(function() {
     var urls=casper.getElementsAttribute('a[href]', 'href');
    casper.eachThen(urls, function(response) {
        var  link=response.data;
        this.thenOpen(demourl, function(response) { 
             if (response == undefined || response.status >= 400) {
                this.echo("failed");
            }
        })

        this.on('http.status.404', function(resource) {
            this.echo('wait, this url is 404: ' + resource.url);
        })
    })
})
```

My Webpage consists of more than 400 links. My code doesn't complete its execution and remains idle after some links. It is not giving me any response. I am not getting why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

## Get link URLs

There is a difference between attributes and properties of DOM elements. If you have a website which is on the domain http://example.com and you want to get the `href` of the following link on that page

```
<a href="/path/to/stuff">text</a>
```

If you use `aElement.getAttribute("href")` you will get `"/path/to/stuff"`, but if you use `aElement.href`, you will get the computed URL `"http://example.com/path/to/stuff"`. Only the latter is a URL that CasperJS (actually PhantomJS) understands.

I'm telling you this, because `casper.getElementsAttribute()` internally uses the `element.getAttribute()` approach which produces URLs that cannot be opened with `casper.thenOpen()`.

The fix is easy:

```
var urls = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'), function(a){
        return a.href;
    });
});
```

Also, you might want to move the `casper.on()` event registration above the `casper.eachThen()` call. You don't need to register the event in every iteration.

## Registering link timeouts

Since you have problems with some URLs not loading (probably because they are broken), you can use [`casper.options.stepTimeout`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#steptimeout) to set a timeout for steps, so that CasperJS won't freeze on some unretrievable URL. You also need to define the `onStepTimeout()` callback, otherwise CasperJS will exit.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var currentURL;
    casper.options.stepTimeout = 10000; // 10 seconds
    casper.options.onStepTimeout = function(timeout, stepNum){
        this.echo('wait, this url timed out: ' + currentURL);
    };

    var urls = this.evaluate(function(){
        return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'), function(a){
            return a.href;
        });
    });
    this.on('http.status.404', function(resource) {
        this.echo('wait, this url is 404: ' + resource.url);
    });
    urls.forEach(function(link) {
        this.then(function(){
            currentURL = link;
        });
        this.thenOpen(link, function(response) { 
             if (response == undefined || response.status >= 400) {
                this.echo("failed: " + link);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My page consists all absolute URLs. I am passing one URL at  a time  to thenOpen and checking their status. but again my code  doesn't complete its execution and remains idle after some links.so how I handle this?

Comment: I don't know why your script idles. Is there something special about the last opened URL? Is it always the same URL that causes it to idle? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: No URL is not same. I register all the events, but it does not give me any error.but again it idle after some links. I don't understand what to do?

Comment: I do not understand why my script idle. Is due to my net connection or any other things. I don't understand what to do?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Have you tried switching to another PhantomJS version? Try both 1.9.8 and 2.0.0. If you installed CasperJS through npm, keep in mind that it also installs and older version of PhantomJS along with it. You should put the other PhantomJS versions on the PATH one at a time.

Comment: I am not installing casperjs through npm my casperjs version is 1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs version is 1.9.8

Comment: can we add timeout in thneOpen() so if URL is timeout we skip that URL  and go for another URL?

Comment: Yes, you can set the [`casper.options.stepTimeout`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#steptimeout).

Comment: But where I  write this? and how I check if particular URL is a timeout or not? Please tell me

Comment: I've extended my answer.